# How to pass extra parameter to Add and Edit url in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Order id is stored in variable _documentId and changed in runtime  by ajax call if new order is saved to actual it.

If adding new detail row to jqGrid Add form url or inline Edit url reqires this id also.
I tried to use postdata but _documentId is not passed if Edit and Add urls are called.
How to pass _documentId value to those urls ?

```
   var _documentId; // assigned from ajax call after save.

   $(function () {
        var grid = $("#grid");
        grid.jqGrid({
            postData: {_documentId: function() { return _documentId } },
            editurl: 'Edit',  // How to pass _documentId value to this controller ?

            url: 'GetData',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            scroll: 1,
            multiselect: true,
            multiboxonly: true, 
            scrollingRows : true,
            autoencode: true,
            prmNames:  {id:"_rowid", oper: "_oper" }, 
            colModel: <%= Model.ColModel() %>,
            gridview: true,
            toppager: true,
            viewrecords: true
            });

      grid.navGrid("#grid_toppager", {}, {}
        { url: 'Add' }  // How to pass _documentId value to this controller ?
      );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of form editing, you should use [editData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) parameter to send additional data to the server. Another way is to modify the postdata inside of [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) or [beforeSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handler. You can of course do it in the [serializeEditData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handler instead. Using `onclickSubmit`, you can easy modify the URL (`params.url`) if you need really place the information in the URL and not in the data which will be send to the server.

In case of inline editing, you can use [extraparam](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) parameter of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) or use [serializeRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) event handler.

Comment: Thank you. I used `editData: { _dokdata: JSON.stringify($("#Form").serializeArray()) }` to pass form data in add,edit format and similar extraparam in inline edit. Posted data contains both keys and JSON data. It would be better if all posted data is in JSON format, but don't know how to force jqgrid to do it so that ASP .NET MVC2 controller can read it. I marked your answer and upvoted it.

Comment: @Andrus: I would prefer the way with `editData: { _dokdata: function() { return JSON.stringify($("#Form").serializeArray()); } }` to be sure that `JSON.stringify` uses not the values existing at the page generation time, but the current data at the posting time. To have more JSON you can use `$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }, ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }, ajaxSelectOptions: { contentType: "application/json", dataType: "JSON" }, serializeRowData: function (data) {return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);}});` and so on

Comment: Thank you. I created function and used `{ _dokdata: FormData }` in inline edit, add and edit form parameters. Hopefully this gets last data always. Controllers look like `public ActionResult Edit(string _rowid, string _entity) { var entity=EntityFactory.Create(_entity); UpdateModel(entity, UpdateModel(entity, new HtmlDecodeValueProvider(ControllerContext)) ... }` How to keep them work if json global parameters are added as you suggested ?

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, I am deep in the work on one project for my customer, so I can't quickly to switch to your problems. I hope that you needs something like `$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }, serializeEditData: function (postdata) { return JSON.stringify(postdata); }});`. It's simplified form of the standard settings which I use. Moreover the setting like `$.extend($.jgrid.del, {ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }});`, `$.extend($.jgrid.search, { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true });` and so on can be also helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it looks like ASP .NET MVC2 does not parse json data in Action, so I cannot use it. I looked and seems that modern ERP APIs also use traditional POST key/value pair format. So I can leave it as is or post _dokdata also in key/value format using jquery serialize() instead of serializearray() for consistency

Comment: @Andrus: ASP.NET MVC **3** can do this. See "JavaScript and AJAX Improvements" part from [the post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx) about the 1-st preview of ASP.NET MVC3.

Comment: I have one server running older Mono which does not support .NET 4. Upgrading it to Mono 2.10 is lot of work, I try to avoid it. To allow application to run in it I must stay in .NET 3.5 . Otherwize I must create two versions of some projects, one for .Net 4 and second for .Net 3.5 which requires lot of uninteresting work

Comment: @Andrus: OK, I understand. In the case you should just has a little less JSON, but it's not a real problem.